# Can we Sacrifice on behalf of Prophet Muhammad (Peace be upon him)?

Tags: sharia, eid, sacrifice, eid-ul-adha

I have planned to buy three goats one my behalf other on my fathers and the third one I have planned on behalf of our Prophet Muhammad (Peace be upon him). So I want to know what Shariya tells about it.

Comment: This is an issue on which there is difference among the madhabs.

Comment: In my family we do it alhamdulillah on every Eid, I don't see anything wrong in that, indeed it is done by many salfo saliheen.

Comment: Already the matter of sacrifice on behalf dead people is discussed with a difference of opinion and only the case of a will seems to be agreed upon. There's AFAIK no report or early Muslims doing this and they lived to see the prophet () or at least are close to his time of life. However the prophet () sacrificed on behalf of his Ummah. Honestly this year I wonder if without hajj (all Muslims know that hajj was canceled in oposition to earlier times) a sacrifice makes sense, but that is only my own contemplation. At least in some locations even buying a sheep could still be hardship.

Comment: because i ve searched some places its written that our beloved Prophet (PBUH) sacrificed on behalf of the poor people which cannot afford so that they may enjoy that moment of eid as well..so besides me and my father share i was wondering if its allowed for Prophet (PBUH)  or for the people....